# why I can't call functions in a Coldfusion CFC on live server when it works on production?

Tags: function, coldfusion, extends, cfc

I'm at a loss.

I'm posting to a Coldfusion8 cfc via Ajax and while it works fine on my local machine, on the live server I cannot call any function in this CFC or it's extended CFC.

I want to do this:

```
<cfset LOCAL.response = THIS.commit() />
```

If I dump:

```
<cfdump output="e:\path\to\dump.txt" label="catch" var="committing"> 
<cfdump output="e:\path\to\dump.txt" label="catch" var="#THIS#"> 
<cfset dickhead = THIS.Commit() >
<cfdump output="e:\path\to\dump.txt" label="catch" var="out">
```

I'm getting:

```
committing 
****************************************************************

catch - component services.form_service_user 
    extends controllers.form_switch

Methods: 
    DEFAULTS
        [function]
            Arguments: none 
            ReturnType: struct 
            Roles:  
            Access: public 
            Output: false 
            DisplayName:  
            Description:  
PROCESS
        [function]
            Arguments: none 
            ReturnType: struct 
            Roles:  
            Access: remote 
            Output: true 
            DisplayName:  
            Description:   
COMMIT
        [function]
            Arguments: none 
            ReturnType: struct 
            Roles:  
            Access: public 
            Output: false 
    Description:  
             ...
```

---

So the methods/functions are there. But I'm not getting to **out**. Also I have cleared out the commit function except for a lone return value and a dump. I'm neither getting the dump nor the return value.

**QUESTION**:
If I'm inside PROCESS, why can I not call COMMIT on the live server when it works fine on production? Is this some kind of caching or whatever setting? Also, I don't have access to the CFadmin, so I'm more or less guessing blind?

Thanks for any infos!

**EDIT**:
The commit call is inside a try/catch:

```
<cftry>     
    <cfdump output="e:\dump.txt" label="catch" var="a"> 
    <cfdump output="e:\dump.txt" label="catch" var="#THIS#"> 
    <cfset LOCAL.Response = THIS.Commit() >
    <cfdump output="e:\dump.txt" label="catch" var="b"> 

    <!--- COMMIT ERRORS --->
    <cfcatch>
            <cfdump output="e:\dump.txt" label="catch" var="ERROR">
            <cfset LOCAL.Response.Success = false />
            <cfset LOCAL.Response.Errors = [["server_error","commit error"]] />     
    </cfcatch>
</cftry>
```

I'm getting the "commit error" returned by AJAX

Comment: Since you're using THIS, I assume you're inside the cfc itself? What is the error that's thrown?

Comment: I don't get one. That's the problem. I DUMP "a" THIS.COMMIT DUMP "b" and I only get "a" in the dump file. Inside THIS.COMMIT I only have DUMP "c", which also does not show up.... clueless

Comment: Do you have an abort or something in commit?

Comment: No, I don't. Good idea. Also see my edit above.

Comment: Call the cfc manually in the url to see the error, instead of ajax handling it.

Comment: @Busches: nice idea. I get this: "Diagnose: There was an error compiling your source code javacTask: no source files
Usage: javacTask <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
<br>The error occurred on line 168". So it seems I'm missing a java file to run the script. I added the file, but I will need to restart the Coldfusion server to get it running, correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the access attribute on your methods.

If you are calling a method in a component (or inherited from a parent component) from another method in the same component, then access must be private, public or package. It cannot be remote.

Make sure your ColdFusion mappings are correct for the live server.

Make sure you have deployed all of the application files to the live server in the right location.

Comment: Seems I'm missing a javaloader file.... somehow did not make it's way to the live server. I added it manually, but in order to see if it works, I will need to restart the server, correct?

Comment: If you are talking about Mark Mandel's javaloader you shouldn't need a restart, but you never know if jrun is going to be nice to you.

Comment: it's the one. And ... I stopped counting restarting my local server until I had the mappings and everything working with Javaloader :-) But I followed all your other tips (access=private as inherited) mapping output is correct, missing file added... and it still doesn't run. So my last option is to restart jrun and CF8.... Monday :-(

Comment: @Stephen, can you please explain what you mean by this: "If you are calling a method in a component [...] from another method in the same component, then access [...] cannot be remote." (omissions for clarity only, I don't think that changes what you said?)

It sounds like you're suggesting one can ONLY call remote methods via a remote call.  This is certainly not my experience.

Am happy to ask another separate question on this rather than clutter the comments up here if you like.  Let me know.

Cheers.

Comment: @adam actually I think that you are right having re-read the CF9 docs. I am not a fan of the remote access type. In past times I've had variable success with it and found it to be misused.